# How to change <input type="text"> value by attribute

Tags: javascript, html, input

I have a program which creates input element by JS (`createElement("INPUT")`). 
I tried to change the value of the element in runtime by changing the attributes `value` and `text` but the attribute changed and the value which I saw in the input box stay in the previous value.

how I could to change the value in runtime?

Comment: changing value should work. Can you post your code?

Comment: The code is part of big and private code, but I dont know how it possible that the value that written in the HTML (when I using inspect) is diffrenet from the value that shows in the input box (and this is the situation.. :|)

Comment: @Lupo113 And how are you setting the value, `querySelector` or`getElementById` ??

Comment: give us your code (working or buggy)

Comment: If you can not post the real code, at least post a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Changing the value of an input’s value as previously shown should work.

> the attribute changed and the value which I saw in the input box stay in the previous value.

However, the real answer the poster is looking for is why the value is not changing as expected.

### Attribute shows initial value

The reason the values does not change in DevTools is because the value attribute will only show the initial value of the input and not any changes to it.

> value
>   The input control's value. When specified in the HTML, this is the initial value, and from then on it can be altered or retrieved at any time using JavaScript to access the respective HTMLInputElement object's value property. The value attribute is always optional.

See [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input).

Answer (score 0):

You can use `.value` to get and change the value property of your newly created element.

Working Snippet Example:

```js
//create text input
var someInput = document.createElement("INPUT");
someInput.setAttribute("type", "text");

//append element to DOM
var myDiv = document.getElementById("someCode");
myDiv.appendChild(someInput);

//change input value
someInput.value = "New Value"
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>Snippet</title>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="someCode">
    
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```